# access file in use problem

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have an Access 2007 database file that should be used by two programs simultaneously.

Program 1 should insert and update the table;
Program 2 should only run queries to show the data.

The problem is, when program 2 opens the file - program 1 cannot insert or update rows.

What can I do?

Comment: How are you connecting to the Access database? Could you provide the code?

Comment: Your current connection string would help a lot, then I'll edit it and attach it to my answer.

Comment: because program 2 is written in C#

Answer (score 1):

This is a permissions problem.  The user or process running program 2 doesn't have write (or create), and preferably delete, priviliges to the folder.  This is required so the LDB locking file can be created so that Access can allow multiple users onto the same database file.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Mutex to restrict only a single instance to access your mdb file.

```
using (Mutex m = new Mutex(false, "Global\\TheNameOfTheMutex")) 
{
        // If you want to wait for 10 seconds for other request to finish            
        m.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),false);
        UpdateDatabase();  // or ReadDatabase();


        // or you can throw error if another process is accessing your database
        //
        //if (!m.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero, false))
        //    throw new Exception("Another instance is updating database.");
        //else
        //    UpdateDatabase();                              

}
```

What this above snippet does is, it will not allow any other instance of your application to call on the UpdateDatabase method while another instance is already accessing your database.

Comment: Er, isn't this exactly the opposite of what is requested, i.e., he wants two simultaneous connections?

Comment: he can not have two simultaneous operations, so he needs to wait before the first one is finished, instead of erroring out.